# edit profile view asp.net-mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am quite new to asp.net mvc5, and in my app I want to retrieve user info in their profile. 
In profile action I'm trying to display the user info and allow them to edit their info too.
But when I run the program I am getting the edit and display view empty. 
I am expecting to see the user previous info when they're trying to edit for example. 
here is a picture of what I want:
[image]

this is my action :

```
       [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult DriverProfile()
        {



            var userManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<AppUserManager>();
            var authManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;

            ProfileModel driver = new ProfileModel();

            IdentityUser theUser = new IdentityUser() { UserName = driver.email, Email = driver.email };


            driver = new ProfileModel(theUser);

            return View("DriverProfile", driver);

        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DriverProfile(ProfileModel profile)
        {
            var manager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(new RidesDbContext()));
            IdentityUser theUser = new IdentityUser() { UserName = profile.email, Email = profile.email };
            IdentityResult theResult = manager.Create(theUser, profile.PasswordHash);

            var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());


            currentUser.UserName = profile.email;
            currentUser.Email = currentUser.Email;


            return Redirect("DriverProfile");
        }
```

I have the profile model as the following:

```
  public class ProfileModel
    {

       public ProfileModel()
        {

        }

        public ProfileModel(IdentityUser theUser)
        {
        }

        [Display(Name = "Id")]
        public int driverId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Pleas Enter Your First Name")]
        public string firstName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Pleas Enter Your Last Name")]
        public string lastName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Pleas Enter Your Email Address")]
        [RegularExpression(".+\\@.+\\..+", ErrorMessage = "Please Enater a Valid Email Address")]
        public string email { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Mobile Number")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Pleas Enter Your Mobile Number")]
        public string phoneNumber { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Address")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Pleas Enter Your Address")]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "City")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Pleas Enter Your City")]
        public string city { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "State")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Pleas Enter Your state")]
        public string state { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Car")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Identify Your Car")]
        public string car { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Driver's License")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Your Driver's Licende Number")]
        public string driverslicense { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Profile Image")]
        [Required]
        public byte[] profileImg { get; set; }

        public string profileImgType { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "License Image")]
        [Required]
        public byte[] licenseImg { get; set; }

        public string licenseImgType { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter a password")]
        public string PasswordHash { get; set; }


    }
```

How would I get the user info in their profile with an edit option?

I would appreciate your help. Thank you.

Edit:

the view is as the following:

```
@model RidesApp.Models.ProfileModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DriverProfile";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/DriversViewPage.cshtml";
}

<h2>DriverProfile</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>ProfileModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.driverId)



        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.firstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.firstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.firstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.lastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.lastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.lastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.phoneNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.phoneNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.phoneNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.city, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.city, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.city, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.state, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.state, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.state, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.car, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.car, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.car, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.driverslicense, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.driverslicense, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.driverslicense, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.profileImgType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.profileImgType, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.profileImgType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.licenseImgType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.licenseImgType, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.licenseImgType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.PasswordHash, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PasswordHash, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PasswordHash, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Edit Profile" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: You should show the view in the question as well.

Comment: I added it, Thank you.

Comment: add the IdentityUser class to your ProfileModel Class

Comment: @Josh Can You demonstrate what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, You want to edit the IdentityUser Class right?

Given that you already assign values in your controller.

First, we add the IdentityUser class to your ProfileModel Class

```
public class ProfileModel{

    public IdentityUser User{get;set;}
    //other profilemodel properties

}
```

on your view:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

or if you just want to show up some values in editing,
you need to assign the value of your ProfileModel

Controller:

```
ProfileModel driver = new ProfileModel();
//code that assigns values to each property
driver.email = "sample@sample.com";
return View("DriverProfile",driver);
```

Comment: I want to edit all the user info, and I'm adding the Identity user because I want to get the user id and using the identity login and after that the user will be able to access the profile view. I have the users edit view in the admin controller works fine because i'm using my own database update method. I am adding the identity framework afterwards. now I have the drivers appear in the drivers table + AspNetUsers table and that why I'm getting confused. Thank You.

Comment: oh in that case do the latter part. You didn't assign any values on your ProfileModel that's why it gave you an empty input fields.

Comment: I did that and still get nothing, besides I'm only able to populate only the identity columns. I can't assign value for other properties I have in the profile model

Comment: hmm have you tried doing `ProfileModel driver = new ProfileModel();
//code that assigns values to each property
driver.email = "sample@sample.com";
return View("DriverProfile",driver);`

if you want the values to show up on your front end. you need to assign the correct value  on your httpget DriverProfile

Comment: `public ActionResult DriverProfile(){ 
  ProfileModel driver = new ProfileModel();
  driver.firstName = "hadeel";
  driver.lastName = "Kh";
  return View("DriverProfile", driver);
}`

try this on your [httpGet] the value should show up. since we are using model binding here

try to remove `ProfileModel()` and `public ProfileModel(IdentityUser theUser)` inside your ProfileModel class